# pyodbc fail to connect to a proxy over ssl for azure sql

Tags: ssl, proxy, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I have an azure sql database setup.

I have one proxy setup which connects to azure sql database on a port say 8444.
The proxy setup has self signed certificate.

When I connect to azure sql database directly using pyodbc.connect(driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}, server={address of azure sql database}, database="master", user={username}, password={password}) it works fine

but when I try to connect through proxy using pyodbc.connect(driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}, server={IP of proxy machine}, port=8444, database="master", user={username}, password={password}, trusted_connection="yes")

I get the error pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I checked proxy is running perfectly fine on the machine.

Comment: Can you try change the connection policy to proxy in SQL database firewall settings?

Comment: **PORT=** attribute doesn't support in Microsoft ODBC.  You need to specify the port like ServerName,Port _i.e.,_ 192.168.0.0,8444